# Error when indexing NumPy array to list containing tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have an NumPy array with a shape of (2143, 3). I am trying to make a list consisting of a tuple containing 3 ints from the numpy array and 1 boolean.

This is the code I'm trying to modify:

```
Voxel = namedtuple('Voxel', 'x y z c')
#This is the tuple

voxels = [ Voxel( nz[0][i], nz[1][i], nz[2][i], True ) for i in range(nz[0].shape[0]) ]
#This is the list
```

For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Double check the `nz.shape`.  If `nz` is indeed (2143,3), then `nz.shape[1]` should be 3; but you are indexing `nz` as though it were `(3,2143)`.  You may have to break the expression into pieces to identify which `tuple` it's talking about. `nz[0].shape` is a tuple.  [0] should be ok unless `nz` is 1d.

Comment: As @hpaulj said, if `nz` is really of shape `(2143, 3)`, then `voxels = [Voxel(*coords, True) for coords in nz]` works. If `nz` is of shape `(3, 2143)` then use `for coords in nz.T`.